# Providing web services through XCode

Tags: xcode, web-services

All,

I'm writing an extensive iPad application with a Core Data based data model. Because the app requires a lot of user input / typing, I would also want to make the functionality available as a web page, so that users can use standard PCs to key in some of the data. 
I'm not particularly worried about the UI for that web app, but I do want to re-use the application logic and Core Data model that I'm using for the iOS app, so my preferred approach would be to expose the functionality as web services on a Mac (using the built-in Apache web server, most likely), using XCode for MacOS.

(1) Are there any existing XCode-based frameworks that simplify the generation of web services?
(2) Am I missing something obvious i.e. is there a better approach to tackle the problem "exposing iOS functionality through a web environment"? Obviously, I could've immediately focused on writing the app in HTML5, but I did want to leverage all the goodies that come with iOS/Cocoa.
(3) Alternatively, I could write a native Mac OS app. That facilitates the re-use of Core Data, etc., but I heard it takes a lot of work to port iOS apps to Mac OS. The question then is what's more work - exposing the functionality as web services or porting it to Mac OS... in both cases, I would need to rewrite the UI.

thanks everyone,
Fabian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research and came across the [WebAppKit](http://webappkit.org) framework. It allows you to easily set up a web server capability and handle requests and responses. It's lightweight, easy to understand - exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want iPhone/iPad users to be able to access the App through the PC web browser to send data/files to the App then take a look @ this one:

http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2008/09/creating-an-iphone-based-web-s.html

Check this question too:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9012/has-anyone-ever-tried-to-use-an-iphone-as-web-server

Comment: Hi Mahmoud,
thanks for the links. I do need to also have the functionality of the iPad serving as web server, so the links are useful. However, they don't answer my initial question: I don't want the services to run on my iOS device, I want to set up a web server on my Mac. And this server needs to provide a lot of functionality which I already coded in my iOS application, hence I want to use XCode to develop the web services. Ideally, I'd expose the services as SOAP services, so I can freely choose what front end development to use. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: you can just install this web server:
http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html which will install Apache automatically then you can develop your SOAP service using PHP

Comment: Yes, I've read about the options of the Mac being a web server, that's not that much the issue. The problem is the second part of your answer - "develop your SOAP service using PHP". I'd like to stick to Objective C and possibly even reuse existing classes to generate the SOAP services. In my old programming environment (Web Dynpro for Java, an application platform for SAP), I could quite easily create SOAP interfaces. I was hoping something similar exists for the XCode platform.

Comment: I am trying to tell you what I was going to do if I were in your place. As fas as I know you cannot achieve that with objective-c. Also PHP is quit easy and c++ like language.